# Order Book Management - Update Market Event

Tags: algorithmic-trading

Given an order book with a bunch of bids and asks, is it possible for an market update event to flip the side of one of the existing open orders from a bid to an ask or vice versa?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little further? describe the full chain of events you're asking about (What happens, in what order, and what causality are you trying to understand).

Comment: @Amit, yes I will try explain further. It simply that an order has come, say, a bid. And then an update to that order has come in subsequently. We all know that price and quantity can change. But I wanted to know whether it was possible to change direction so from a bid to an ask for example. I wasn't sure if this is possible or not. It turns out that it rarely happens as most exchanges I think don't allow it.

Comment: I edited your question to make it more obvious that this is what you meant. At least to me that was very confusing.. I was under the impression you wanted to know if a data update can cause a change in an order.

Comment: I reverted the edit as I believe the question is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **YES**

But it depends on the exchange, if it supports updating only the buy-or-sell status of an active order. A few exchanges support this. However, I believe it is quite rarely occuring in practice.

Comment: At least one of us misunderstood the question. I "understand it" as: is a change in a single order (order A) capable of changing a different order (order B)? I guess you read the question differently, so I'm curious to know how. (And as a side note, I don't think it's polite to mock an answer like you did. You can express your opinion with such practices)

Comment: Hey Amit, sure. I interpret the question pretty straight forward, so I don't really understand how I can explain further how I read the question?

Comment: They key point here is: what do you think *market update* is in OP? I understand that as an update to the book, as a result of a change in one of the orders (or a new order arrived...). That can't by itself change a different order (apart from the one that cause the market update) from being at the bid to being at the ask (or vice versa...)

Comment: Well technically a few exchanges allow just that; changing a bid into an offer. It's a technicality.

Comment: Yes I know you could change an order from a buy to a sell, but can that happen "automatically"? as a result of an external market event?

Comment: Me changing my order from bid to ask would constitute a market update event for you (and for me).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not understanding the question. You're definitely not understanding me. Added a comment on question, lets see what OP has to say...

Comment: Yes I understand you, I just think that you simply are wrong.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. That's what I found. It rarely happens in practice. I just needed to be absolutely sure so that I could determine whether to code for it or not. In my case, the exchange does not support this. Cheers!

Comment: @I.K. no worries, good luck. Please mark the answer as correct if you are happy with it. By the way, I'm not sure a proper implementation of handling market updates needs to know what you are asking.